# Cannot connect by mongoDB Atlas URI using mongoose in node

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to connect my atlas cluster URI in my node project 
Node version: 12.4.1
mongoose: 5.2.7

this is how my URL looks alike

```
mongoose.connect(mongodb+srv://usernane:pass@uri/db_name?authSource=db_name&w=1, {
        useCreateIndex: true,
        keepAlive: 1,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    });
```

I am facing error authentication failed, What I am doing wrong any help will be appreciated.

Comment: something might be wrong at username or password?

Comment: Nope I had tried with same connection in MongoDB GUI tool and its work fine there

Comment: `mongodb+srv://username:<password>@cluster0-vntnn.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority` this is how MongoDB atlas cluster look like diffrent from yours check once

Answer (score 0):

The format and/or query parameters of the connection string you've provided for MongoDB Atlas looks incorrect.
Please ensure, the format is as follows:

```
mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster-id>.mongodb.net/<db-name>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

(The above is taken from MongoDB Atlas connection example)

If, after the above correction - you still face auth issues, I suggest checking with details and possibly create a test user from your Atlas dashboard - [docs on authentication](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/troubleshoot-connection/#authentication-to-the-cluster-failed).

Answer (score 0):

First things first, i prefer to await the connect method, to handle any possible errors. So something like:

```
try {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', { useNewUrlParser: 
  true});
} catch (error) {
  handleError(error);
}
```

Secondly, if password contains special characters, they should be URL encoded. You can use this tool: https://www.urlencoder.org/

Finally, in my case, i did not know i had to allow my current ip address to mongoDB atlas.
While in atlas:

1. click on your cluster then on the left side
2. under security click Network access
3. on the right click ADD IP ADDRESS.

This should fix it.